# Using Substitution variable in PL/SQL Code

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am using SQL Developer and writing this PL/SQL code. But I am getting error, when i gave B as option. Please help.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

accept q_grade char prompt 'EnterGrade: '
DECLARE
v_grade CHAR(1) := UPPER(&q_grade);
v_appraisal VARCHAR(20);

BEGIN
v_appraisal := CASE v_grade WHEN v_grade = 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
WHEN v_grade = 'B' THEN 'Good'
WHEN v_grade = 'C' THEN 'FAIL'
ELSE 'NO SUCH GRADES'
END;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Grade:  ' || v_grade  || ' Appraisal  ' ||v_appraisal);

END;
/
```

Error report:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 26:
PLS-00201: identifier 'B' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 9:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 21:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 57:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 12, column 21:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Put single quotes around `&q_grade`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
v_grade CHAR(1) := UPPER('&q_grade');
```

and

```
v_appraisal := CASE WHEN v_grade = 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the extra `v_grade` right after the `CASE` statement:

```
BEGIN
v_appraisal := CASE WHEN v_grade = 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
/* -- here --------^ */
```

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - whoooops!  You're right - I shouldn't try to look at code at midnight.  :-)  Earlier comment deleted.